# Customize Firebase / Google Identity Platform Multifactor Authentication Confirmation Email

Tags: firebase-authentication, multi-factor-authentication, two-factor-authentication, google-identity

I have successfully and deceivingly easily added Firebase authentication for my web ap. I've found during my work that it's actually just a wrapper over the identity platform product from GCP. I've found this out while working on adding two factor authentication via phone for the app as well.

Everything works fine for the amount of complexity 2fa brings.

The problem I am now facing is that every time I enroll a user to the second factor, they get a horrendous automatically generated email which I just can't seem to understand where to change.
I know that transactional emails are a bit unwieldy in Firebase, so I fear the worse on customization, which is why I am asking:

Where do you change, or disable that email? I am already notifying the user their phone was validated and they just got the SMS on their phone, there is no need for another ugly notification.

That said, the documentation does say an email will be delivered upon running the [`multiFactoruser.enroll`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.user.multifactoruser#enroll) method, but not much else.

I've also [found](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/manage-mfa-users#updating_a_user) that the identity platform allows for programmatic enrollment via the admin SDK which is I guess my next plan if the email cannot be disabled.

This seems straightforward enough, but I'm wondering if it will also send a validation SMS or that is simply it, if the user adds a wrong phone, they will then be locked out of their account.

Comment: Can you check this [google document](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/work-with-mfa-users) to see if it helps. I haven't found a way to stop the email from being sent, but you can customize the verification email the end user receives.

Comment: Hi, yes I have checked most of the documentation at length. Indeed you can customize that sender email to your domain instead of the one ending in firebaseapp.com but still, my business requirements are colorful cheery emails so I can't use that black on white text one. 

I believe I will try Twillio 2fa and a protected firestore table so I can know the users 2fa enrolment status, since there is also a bug with SMS not being sent all of the time. 

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are feeling very well. I came across this question and stopped to answer it.

As you mentioned, it is not possible to modify the Firebase email Templates since there may be malicious use, however, there is a way for you to create your templates and make them visible to your users instead of the default email and without structure that Firebase use.
[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links) I leave the documentation that you should follow, for that, you need an SMTP service that you must configure in the Firebase-Authentication console and then follow the documentation that I shared this is available for all Authentication Email Templates:

- Email address verification
- Password reset
- Email address change
- ***Multi-factor enrollment notification***